# Populate Id's Based on another table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have the following Table:

[image: Sample Data 1]

The sample data for above is as following:

```
declare @years table (idYear int primary key identity, cYearDescription varchar(20), dYearStartDate datetime)

insert into @years (cYearDescription,dYearStartDate) values
    ('Year 1','2014-08-31')
,   ('Year 2','2015-07-01')
,   ('Year 3','2016-07-01')
,   ('Year 4','2017-07-01')
,   ('Year 5','2018-07-01')
,   ('Year 6','2019-07-01')

select
*
from    @years
```

Notice the Start Date for where `idYear = 1` is the end of that month. I've provided the sample data this way, as it's exactly how it is in my actual table...

I then generate the End of each month for all the periods in between these months with this script:

```
;with cte as
(
select  dateadd(day, nbr - 1, (select min(dYearStartDate) from @years)) CalendarDate
from    ( select    row_number() over ( order by c.object_id ) as nbr
          from      sys.columns c
        ) nbrs
where   nbr - 1 <= datediff(day, (select min(dYearStartDate) from @years), (select max(dYearStartDate) from @years))
)
,   months as (
select
eomonth(CalendarDate)   EndOfMonth
from    cte
group by eomonth(CalendarDate)
)

select
*
from    months
```

I then join the `cte` with my virtual table like following:

```
declare @years table (idYear int primary key identity, cYearDescription varchar(20), dYearStartDate datetime)

insert into @years (cYearDescription,dYearStartDate) values
    ('Year 1','2014-08-31')
,   ('Year 2','2015-07-01')
,   ('Year 3','2016-07-01')
,   ('Year 4','2017-07-01')
,   ('Year 5','2018-07-01')
,   ('Year 6','2019-07-01')


;with cte as
(
select  dateadd(day, nbr - 1, (select min(dYearStartDate) from @years)) CalendarDate
from    ( select    row_number() over ( order by c.object_id ) as nbr
          from      sys.columns c
        ) nbrs
where   nbr - 1 <= datediff(day, (select min(dYearStartDate) from @years), (select max(dYearStartDate) from @years))
)
,   months as (
select
eomonth(CalendarDate)   EndOfMonth
from    cte
group by eomonth(CalendarDate)
)

select
*
from    months m
left join @years y  on  eomonth(dYearStartDate) = EndOfMonth
order by EndOfMonth
```

The above gives me the following results:

[image: Results]

How do I manipulate this to look as follows:

[image: Expected Results]

I've tried `rank`, `ntile` and `row_number`, but none give me the results I require...

Your assistance is much appreciated!

**EDIT**

I've altered the `select` above to the following:

```
select
*
,   isnull(idYear,lag(idYear) over (order by EndOfMonth))   idYear
,   (select idYear from @years where year(dYearStartDate) = year(EndOfMonth))   idYear
from    months m
left join @years y  on  eomonth(dYearStartDate) = EndOfMonth
order by EndOfMonth
```

But as can be seen, it's not looking like my expected results:

[image: No Luck]

Comment: It's great you've posted sample data as DDL+DML, however the images are not helping to understand the question, they only make it harder (at least for me). A clear textual representation of the desired output next to the current output would help a lot more.

Comment: Apologies @ZoharPeled, I need the `idYear`, to be repeated for every month that is `NULL`, but as can be seen from my **EDIT**, my attempts gives me the wrong `idYear` (Last Column) - Hope that explains it better...?

Comment: i.e. from row 1 to row 11, I need the `idYear` to be 1, from row 12 to 23, I need the `idYear` to be 2, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can work around this, was to add an `End Date` to my table using `LEAD`, which worked.

With that stated, I am able to query the `idYear` between these dates as following:

```
select
*
,       iif(idYear is null,(select idYear from LeadDateAdded where EndOfMonth between dYearStartDate and dYearEndDate),idYear)  idYear
from    months m
left join LeadDateAdded y   on  eomonth(dYearStartDate) = EndOfMonth
order by EndOfMonth
```

The full and final code looks like this:

```
declare @years table (idYear int primary key identity, cYearDescription varchar(20), dYearStartDate datetime)

insert into @years (cYearDescription,dYearStartDate) values
    ('Year 1','2014-08-31')
,   ('Year 2','2015-07-01')
,   ('Year 3','2016-07-01')
,   ('Year 4','2017-07-01')
,   ('Year 5','2018-07-01')
,   ('Year 6','2019-07-01')
,   ('Year 7','2020-07-01')


;with cte as
(
select  dateadd(day, nbr - 1, (select min(dYearStartDate) from @years)) CalendarDate
from    ( select    row_number() over ( order by c.object_id ) as nbr
          from      sys.columns c
        ) nbrs
where   nbr - 1 <= datediff(day, (select min(dYearStartDate) from @years), (select max(dYearStartDate) from @years))
)
,   months as (
select
eomonth(CalendarDate)   EndOfMonth
from    cte
group by eomonth(CalendarDate)
)
,   Years as (
select
    idYear
,   cYearDescription
,   dYearStartDate
,   cast(lead(eomonth(dYearStartDate)) over (order by idYear) as datetime)  dYearEndDate
from    @years
)

select
*
,       iif(idYear is null,(select idYear from Years where EndOfMonth between dYearStartDate and dYearEndDate),idYear)  idYear
from    months m
left join Years y   on  eomonth(dYearStartDate) = EndOfMonth
order by EndOfMonth
```

The results are as following (Last Column is the result I needed):

[image: Results]

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try getting the information for each year from the @years table by joining YEAR(@years.dYearStartDate) and YEAR(month.EndOfMonth), like so:

```
select a.EndOfMonth, b.idYear, b.cYearDescription, b.dYearStartDate
 from (
    select year(m.EndOfMonth) curYear, *
       from months m
     left join @years y  
       on  eomonth(dYearStartDate) = EndOfMonth) a
   inner join (select year(dYearStartDate) curYear, * from @years) b
     on a.curYear = b.curYear
   order by EndOfMonth
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work, because according to my `@year` table, my period starts August 2014 and ends June 2015, which is the dilemma I'm facing, the Period needs to be 1 for this specific time. For Period 2, my start date is July 2015 and end is June 2015, which should be the `idYear` of 2, etc.